# How do you configure an HP LaserJet 5000N printer using the front control panel to have a static IP?

Tags: configuration, hp, printing, network-printer

What are the steps required to configure static IP for an HP LaserJet 5000N printer using the front control panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on **[THIS](http://bizsupport2.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/bpl05322/bpl05322.pdf)** link, go to page B-18, it explains how to setup IP on the machine.

Comment: +1 for saving me the trouble of searching for the User's Guide. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found detailed steps at the [HP Support Document for Configuring TCP/IP through the Front Control Panel](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?locale=en_US&taskId=115&prodSeriesId=27347&prodTypeId=18972&objectID=bpj02326&printver=true#A5). The steps are summarized below for convenience.

HP LaserJet 4000, 4050, 4100, 4500, 4550, 5Si, 5SiMX, 5000, 5100, 8500, 8550, 8000, 8150 printers, HP 2500c Professional series, HP Business Inkjet 2200, 2250, and 2600 printers
To configure TCP/IP parameters from the control panel, use the following instructions:

1. Press the MENU button until HP MIO 1 (or 2) , or HP EIO 1 (or 2) appears.
2. Press the ITEM button until CFG NETWORK = NO appears.
3. Press the PLUS or VALUE button until CFG NETWORK = YES appears.

   NOTE:     The CFG NETWORK = XXX (XXX being YES or NO) is a toggle, not a permanent setting. Changing it to YES allows the settings to be changed at that time . It will appear as CFG NETWORK = NO each time this menu is accessed.
4. Press SELECT or RESUME.
5. Press ITEM repeatedly until CFG TCP/IP = NO appears.
6. Press the PLUS or VALUE button until CFG TCP/IP = YES appears.

   NOTE:    The CFG TCP/IP = XXX (XXX being YES or NO) is a toggle, not a permanent setting. Changing it to YES allows the settings to be changed at that time . It will appear as CFG TCP/IP = NO each time this menu is accessed.
7. Press SELECT or RESUME .
8. Press the ITEM repeatedly until BOOTP = YES* appears.
9. Press the PLUS or VALUE button until BOOTP = NO appears.

   NOTE: When using BootP or DHCP, keep the setting BOOTP = YES *. The BootP or DHCP server will configure the TCP/IP parameters on the HP Jetdirect. No other TCP/IP configuring is necessary.
10. Press SELECT or RESUME .

    The following two steps apply to the HP Jetdirect 610n cards only:

    a. DHCP=YES appears.

    b. Press the PLUS or VALUE button until DHCP = NO appears.

    NOTE:    When using DHCP, keep the setting DHCP = YES *. The DHCP server will configure the TCP/IP parameters on the HP Jetdirect. No other TCP/IP configuring is necessary.
11. Press SELECT or RESUME .
12. Press ITEM until IP BYTE 1 = (value*) appears.
13. Press the PLUS or VALUE button, until the desired value of the first byte of the IP address appears. By pressing and holding the PLUS or VALUE button, the value will scroll rapidly (HP LaserJet 4000, 5000, and 8000 printers have a MINUS button to decrease the value).
14. Press SELECT or RESUME to save the value.
15. Press ITEM to continue. Repeat Steps 11-13 to configure the remaining bytes of the IP address.
16. Repeat Steps 11-13 to configure the subnet mask bytes (SM BYTE 1=), syslog server IP address (LG BYTE 1=), default gateway (GW BYTE 1=), and timeout (TIMEOUT=).
17. Press ONLINE , GO or MENU . Print a self-test page to verify the IP settings.
18. If the test page does not show the correct settings, power cycle the printer and reprint the test page.

Comment: Can whoever down voted this answer, please leave a comment as to why just to satisfy my curiosity and so that I can become a better ServerFault participant? Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

The only way to set a static address is to do it with your DHCP server.  Find the the MAC address of the machine by printing the configuration page then assign the static IP you want to give it at the DHCP server.

Comment: That's...erm, don't quite know how to put this...completely and entirely incorrect - see either of the two other answers.

Comment: It is true that you can set it from the panel however the you should still set the DHCP server to give the address you want to the printer so it does not get given out via DHCP to another device if the printer is turned off for a while say over along weekend

Comment: that makes no sense at all, why use DHCP at all for a printer, even if you have to you just add it as a reservation so it'll never be handed out - I don't get your point.

Comment: That is my point exactly.  You need to set the DHCP server to only give out the address to one particular MAC.  Since you are going to make the reservation on the server why go through all of the trouble to set the address on the printer.  I have 15 network printers on my network (I know that is not alot) so why should I do double work by assigning the address in 2 places just leave the printer set to its default which is to use DHCP and set the address on the server.

Comment: And not only do you have to set the IP address manually but you also have to set the subnet mask and default gateway manually.  Much easier to set the reservation on the server and let it get it from DHCP than to mess around with all of that.